# Criar servidor xmpp

Tags: c#, xmpp

Gostaria de saber se ainda existe a possibilidade de escrever um **SERVIDOR** **XMPP** em C#. Já tentei procurar pela internet, em muitos sites, e eles só disponibilizam o **CLIENTE**. Não sei se o cliente pode ser usado para essa função, sei que **XMPP** é bem antigo, porém preciso disso pra trabalhar com um sistema de um game.

OBS: Já tentei OpenFire e Jabber, porém eu quero trabalhar com queries customizadas, e conexão com banco de dados, conectar-se a um servidor dedicado, etc.

Comment: Quando você diz `queries customizadas` significa customizar o retorno de uma solicitação?

Comment: sim, por exemplo nesse projeto que estou trabalhando do game, ele retorna get e result, com informações como por exemplo, criar uma sala de jogo, comprar algum item na loja etc.

Comment: Tentei utilizar TcpListener, pra ver se teria como ele retornar, mas precisa dos eventos, OnConnect, e OnAuthenticate que no XMPP tem!

Comment: Exemplo de pegar as conquistas do jogador:
`<iq from='masterserver@game/xxx' type='result'>
        <query>
         <get_achievements>
          <achievement profile_id="1597755">
           <chunk achievement_id="52" progress="522318" completion_time="0"/>
           <chunk achievement_id="53" progress="522318" completion_time="0"/>
           <chunk achievement_id="54" progress="10" completion_time="1459026091"/>
          </achievement>
         </get_achievements>
        </query>
       </iq>`

Comment: Eu até conheço o xmpp-server em .js mas não entendo muito de NodeJS

Comment: Fiz um trabalho pra faculdade a muito tempo, cheguei a tentar algo parecido (customizar requisições/retornos no servidor) mas com o tempo era curto deixei decidi não implementar. Acho que teria que mexer no servidor (`Java`) e estudar `XMPP` para fazer o que pretende.  `XMPP` é antigo mas é poderoso, salvo engano, Whatsapp ainda usa uma versão própria.